# Spring MVC + Thymeleaf: passing objects through pages

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm developing a simple web application using spring MVC and thymeleaf. I have a form correctly handled by this method in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView searchJob(
        @ModelAttribute(SEARCH_PARAMS) @Valid SearchParams params,
        BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ModelAndView output = null;

    if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

        JobsAPIImplService service = new JobsAPIImplService();
        JobsAPI api = service.getJobsAPIImplPort();

        ArrayList<NoaJob> jobs = (ArrayList<NoaJob>) (api.search(JobUtils.toSearchParams(params))).getItem();

        output = new ModelAndView("scheduler/list");
        output.addObject("jobs", jobs);
    } else { 
     // errors handling
    }

    return output;
}
```

So in my result page I can access to the ArrayList "jobs" in this way:

```
<tr th:each="job : ${jobs}">
    ...
</tr>
```

In the same page, I have a simple link which calls another GET method on the same controller. The goal here is to have the same ArrayList in another page in order to implement a "back" button without re-executing the search logic (a call to a web service). 
Here is the method called

```
@RequestMapping(value="/list/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView details(@PathVariable("id") String jobUuid,
        @ModelAttribute("jobs") ArrayList<NoaJob> jobs) {
    ModelAndView output = new ModelAndView("scheduler/details");

    LOGGER.info("Size jobs list: " + jobs.size());

    NoaJob job = new NoaJob();
    job.setJobUuid(jobUuid);
    output.addObject("job", job);
    output.addObject("jobs", jobs);

    return output;
}
```

the problem is that the arraylist here is always null! I read that in GET requests Spring allocates a new ModelAttribute, so how can I pass this object throug pages?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that though? What if the web service returns a different set of results this time?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. I think that for the user it will be quite confusing find other data after have clicked a "back" button. My business requirements are not so strict.

Comment: In that case and since it's a search, I'd recommend using just a normal GET instead of a POST just use the normal back button every browser has? It will return the user to the previous page redoing the query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a session attribute like this in the head of your controller:

```
    @SessionAttributes({ "myFancyList"})
    @Controller
    public class HomeController {
      // your code here
    }
```

Now.. when you have to insert the "list" to be viewable via thymeleaf:

```
output.addObject("myFancyList", jobs);
```

and modify thymleaf pseudocode accordingly.

in the "post" of the search "override" the session attribute with the current search result..

i think this should do the trick for you

Comment: using session attributes seems to be the right answer here. Thank you.

Comment: just a necrobump though. please when using sessionattributes beware of the actual usage you have to do, especially in context of multiple tabs open on the SAME functionality with DIFFERENT "instances" on the session attributes.. this is one of the most critical issues with spring mvc :)